# Cannot perform find operation on Installation class even without permission

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've already asked this question on parse community but I haven't received any answers.

My Installation class has permissions that would enable client to do any operation on it:
[image]

However, when I try to query on the class, it gives me the error:

> Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the
>   installation collection.

Here is my sample query:

```
ParseQuery mainquery = new ParseInstallation().getQuery();
mainquery.whereMatchesQuery("user", innerQuery);
mainquery.findInBackground();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` before the first line of your cloud code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible from a client (as the error message also states). You would need to use cloud code and master key. Check this question for an example:
https://www.parse.com/questions/find-operation-on-installation-class