# Parse: Unauthorized when querying ParseInstallation

Tags: java, parse-platform

I have this code to query an installation by `uniqueId` custom field in [Parse](http://www.parse.com):

```
public static void init(Context context) {
    Parse.initialize(context, Constants.PARSE_APP_ID, Constants.PARSE_APP_KEY);

    String wifiMacAddress = getWifiMacAddress(context);

    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("uniqueId", wifiMacAddress);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseInstallation>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseInstallation> parseInstallations, ParseException e) {
            if (parseInstallations == null)
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            Log.d("prova", "Size: " + parseInstallations.size());
        }
    });
}
```

But I get a `ParseRequestException`:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: unauthorized

I'm using the Parse master key. If I use the client key instead, I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779274/cannot-perform-find-operation-on-installation-class-even-without-permission and https://www.parse.com/questions/find-operation-on-installation-class?

Comment: Which is the equivalent to `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` in Java SDK?

Comment: I have the permissions of Installation class in Public R/W

Comment: Give [ParseCloud.callFunction()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseCloud.html#callFunction(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)) a try. (maybe it works even though the js api says "Available in Cloud Code and Node.js only.")

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you intended this, but the method [`Parse.initialize(Context, String, String)`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/Parse.html#initialize(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says

> This method is only required if you intend to use **a different
>   applicationId or clientKey** than is defined by com.parse.APPLICATION_ID
>   or com.parse.CLIENT_KEY in your AndroidManifest.xml.

So the default would be to define both in `AndroidManifest.xml`, as

> ```
> <manifest ...>
>
>  ...
>
>    <application ...>
>      <meta-data
>        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
>        android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
>      <meta-data
>        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
>        android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />
>
>        ...
>
>    </application>
>  </manifest>
> ```

and to use `initialize(Context context)`.

BTW, [`initialize`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/Parse.html#initialize(android.content.Context)) expects

> The client key provided in the Parse dashboard.

Comment: Well, I'm using `Parse.initialize(Context, String, String)` beacuse I'm declaring the keys in a Constants class instead of in manifest. But that is not the problem, since it is working for me. Problem occurs when I try to query a Installation.

Comment: +1 I realized my key in Parse.initialize(Context, String, String) was off by a letter; don't know how I lost a letter in between the string!